# restore all the Fragments from backstack in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

Assume: I have an **Activity** and I'm loading **3 fragments** and also added them to **Back Stack**.

Reality: I have more than 3 Fragments and they are loaded based on some condition and are not Fixed in some particular order.

**Initially 1** will be **loaded** then on click of a button inside 1, **2** will **replace 1**. Similar behaviour on 2 Fragment will replace it by 3 fragment.

**3 Fragment opens camera** to capture an image, Now smtimes the Activity 
process is killed and after returning from camera, **Activity is recreated and it loads 1st Fragment**.

I managed to load 3rd Fragment by SaveInstanceState(), but then on press of Back button App exits, coz the Fragment 1 and 2 are not loaded. How can I load 1 then 2 and finally 3 Fragment?

I also tried android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" on that Activity but didn't worked...

Edit:

Save Fragment State -

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "savedFragment", fragment);
    }
```

Restore Fragment state inside **onCreate()**-

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
    fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "savedFragment");
    loadFrag3();
}else {
    loadFrag1();
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @Krish: u mean Save/Restore 3 Fragment?

Comment: activity class maybe .

Comment: @Krish: Added save/restore code. I think I'd like to save Activity Back stack state any idea how that can be done?

Comment: From my point of vie you dont have to do any thing if the savedInstanceState not null. Just use the else case . In oncreate() method.

Comment: @Krish: then it only loads 1 Fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141355/discussion-between-krish-and-kevz).